# Multiplying two columns from different data frames in spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes representing the following csv data:

```
Store   Date    Weekly_Sales
1   05/02/2010  249
2   12/02/2010  455
3   19/02/2010  415
4   26/02/2010  194

Store   Date    Weekly_Sales
5   05/02/2010  400
6   12/02/2010  460
7   19/02/2010  477
8   26/02/2010  345
```

What i'm attempting to do is for each date, read the associated weekly sales for it in both dataframes and find the average of the two numbers. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to have individual store data in the result data set, one approach would be to union the two dataframes and use Window function to calculate average weekly sales (along with the corresponding list of stores, if wanted), as follows:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, "05/02/2010", 249),
  (2, "12/02/2010", 455),
  (3, "19/02/2010", 415),
  (4, "26/02/2010", 194)
).toDF("Store", "Date", "Weekly_Sales")

val df2 = Seq(
  (5, "05/02/2010", 400),
  (6, "12/02/2010", 460),
  (7, "19/02/2010", 477),
  (8, "26/02/2010", 345)
).toDF("Store", "Date", "Weekly_Sales")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val window = Window.partitionBy($"Date")

df1.union(df2).
  withColumn("Avg_Sales", avg($"Weekly_Sales").over(window)).
  withColumn("Store_List", collect_list($"Store").over(window)).
  orderBy($"Date", $"Store").
  show

// +-----+----------+------------+---------+----------+
// |Store|      Date|Weekly_Sales|Avg_Sales|Store_List|
// +-----+----------+------------+---------+----------+
// |    1|05/02/2010|         249|    324.5|    [1, 5]|
// |    5|05/02/2010|         400|    324.5|    [1, 5]|
// |    2|12/02/2010|         455|    457.5|    [2, 6]|
// |    6|12/02/2010|         460|    457.5|    [2, 6]|
// |    3|19/02/2010|         415|    446.0|    [3, 7]|
// |    7|19/02/2010|         477|    446.0|    [3, 7]|
// |    4|26/02/2010|         194|    269.5|    [4, 8]|
// |    8|26/02/2010|         345|    269.5|    [4, 8]|
// +-----+----------+------------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *first merge them using `union` function*. Then *grouping on Date column find the average* ( using `avg` *inbuilt function*) as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df1.union(df2)
  .groupBy("Date")
  .agg(collect_list("Store").as("Stores"), avg("Weekly_Sales").as("average_weekly_sales"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----------+------+--------------------+
|Date      |Stores|average_weekly_sales|
+----------+------+--------------------+
|26/02/2010|[4, 8]|269.5               |
|12/02/2010|[2, 6]|457.5               |
|19/02/2010|[3, 7]|446.0               |
|05/02/2010|[1, 5]|324.5               |
+----------+------+--------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful